# How to pass Receipt Order ID on second windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1, there a button without any textbox. When I click on the button I need to generate an Order ID on form2. Just like in restaurants bills. I've tried passing values in textbox successfully but I just want to generate ID when clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, just pass your Id in the constructor of your form2 (I supose it's an int)
In Form1 class you create a Form2 with:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(orderID);
```

in your Form2 class replace the default constructor Form2() with this

```
Form2( int id)
{ 
    ...
    //you can now use your Order Id in this form
}
```